# Search over multiple key of field type hash MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, mongoid

I would like to apply filter over multiple key of field type hash Reference example code below

######Working Code

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :lD,    as: :load_date,       type:Time
  field :cls,   as: :classification,  type:Hash

  def self.base_filter(filters)
    Model.where("cls.#{filters}.r"=>true,"cls.#{filters}.t"=>"news",:load_date.gte=>1.month.ago).count
  end
end
```

######Desired but not Working Code

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :lD,    as: :load_date,       type:Time    
  field :cls,   as: :classification,  type:Hash

  def self.base_filter(filters)
    Model.where("cls.#{filters}"=>{'r'=>true,'t'=>"news"},:load_date.gte=>1.month.ago).count
  end
end
```

is there is something like this Available in MongoID or if its available in MongoDB than how can i call it from MongoID